# NVidia driver spontaneously uninstalls

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, unattended-upgrades

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop in a (mostly) unattended setup. The machine has a beefy NVidia video card. I had installed the drivers using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and everything worked great.

Nobody ran `apt` after that point.

A few weeks later, when the machine rebooted, it stayed on a **black screen with a blinking cursor**... I had to manually re-run the following to get it to work again:

```
sudo apt -y purge ~nnvidia
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If I look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` I see, at the time when the nvidia drivers spontaneously stopped working:

```
Start-Date: 2022-09-02  11:16:07
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13)
End-Date: 2022-09-02  11:16:08

Start-Date: 2022-09-02  11:16:11
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13), libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13), curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13)
End-Date: 2022-09-02  11:16:13
```

I guess the `unattended-upgrade` was the cause, but why? I suppose disabling `unattended-upgrade` is the only solution?

I also see the following in the `unattended-upgrades.log` :

```
2022-09-01 06:05:58,811 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2022-09-01 06:05:58,813 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security
2022-09-01 06:05:58,813 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2022-09-01 06:05:58,813 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2022-09-01 06:06:37,215 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2022-09-01 06:06:37,355 INFO Package libnvidia-cfg1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,356 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,358 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,360 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,361 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,363 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,365 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,367 INFO Package libnvidia-extra-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,369 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,371 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,373 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,375 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,450 INFO Package linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,484 INFO Package nvidia-compute-utils-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,486 INFO Package nvidia-driver-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,488 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-common-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,490 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-source-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,492 INFO Package nvidia-utils-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:06:37,557 INFO Package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-01 06:26:47,067 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2022-09-01 06:26:47,071 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security
2022-09-01 06:26:47,071 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2022-09-01 06:26:47,071 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2022-09-02 03:57:48,204 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2022-09-02 03:57:48,204 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security
2022-09-02 03:57:48,205 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2022-09-02 03:57:48,205 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2022-09-02 11:15:51,908 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2022-09-02 11:15:51,909 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security
2022-09-02 11:15:51,909 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2022-09-02 11:15:51,909 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2022-09-02 11:16:06,882 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: curl libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev
2022-09-02 11:16:06,882 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2022-09-02 11:16:15,056 INFO All upgrades installed
2022-09-02 11:16:15,351 INFO Package libnvidia-cfg1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,352 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,353 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,355 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,356 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,357 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,359 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,360 INFO Package libnvidia-extra-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,361 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,362 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,364 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,365 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,402 INFO Package linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,418 INFO Package nvidia-compute-utils-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,420 INFO Package nvidia-driver-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,421 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-common-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,422 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-source-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,424 INFO Package nvidia-utils-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-09-02 11:16:15,454 INFO Package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
```

Thank you!

Comment: To verify what got installed and uninstalled, look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: Thank you @Jos ! I have added info to the original question.

Comment: Maybe `dkms` is broken. When kernel upgrades, it doesn't build the Nvidia module. Please add output of `dkms status`.

Comment: I just checked and I had to install `dkms` (wasn't yet installed). Could that be the problem? After install status shows empty...

That said, in the unattended-upgrade log that I posted, it doesn't *look* like th kernel was upgraded?

Comment: Added more from the `unattended-upgrades.log`